# Apache shows Magento directory index after installation (local dev setup)

Tags: apache2, local

So this is a bit of a debugging question, but I do not have any idea what else to try.

I am new to Magento and I wanted to set up a local instance of it to fiddle around.
I followed effectively [this](https://ccbill.com/kb/how-to-install-magento-in-linux) tutorial. After everything is done, trying to open the Magento site on browser merely shows the index of the directory Magento is installed on, as shown below:
[image]

On the same machine, another test pure php page works fine.
I will post the Apache configuration of the site and the configuration of Magento as shown by the `magento config:show` command. Feel free to ask whatever other configuration or log is needed to find out what is happening.

Site Apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin admin@localhost
     DocumentRoot /var/www/magento2.4/pub

     <Directory /var/www/html/magento2.4/pub>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
#       Require all granted
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Magento config output:

```
$ sudo -u www-data /var/www/magento2.4/bin/magento config:show
yotpo/module_info/yotpo_installation_date - 2021-05-08
yotpo/sync_settings/orders_sync_start_date - 2021-05-08
catalog/search/engine - elasticsearch7
catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_hostname - localhost
catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_port - 9200
catalog/category/root_id - 2
web/seo/use_rewrites - 1
web/unsecure/base_url - http://localhost/
general/locale/code - en_US
general/locale/timezone - America/Chicago
general/region/display_all - 1
general/region/state_required - AU,BG,BR,CA,CH,CN,CO,EE,ES,HR,IN,IT,LT,LV,MX,PL,RO,US,UY
currency/options/base - USD
currency/options/default - USD
currency/options/allow - USD
analytics/subscription/enabled - 1
crontab/default/jobs/analytics_subscribe/schedule/cron_expr - 0 * * * *
crontab/default/jobs/analytics_collect_data/schedule/cron_expr - 00 02 * * *
msp_securitysuite_recaptcha/frontend/enabled - 0
msp_securitysuite_recaptcha/backend/enabled - 0
twofactorauth/duo/application_key - FLUe5W1ndlNSCOt5ah5IUluRgIbO2ahoz8pWOVykoky06biGd0Aisvdw1slOIIfX
connector_dynamic_content/external_dynamic_content_urls/passcode - V1QrRRz31I7TUG0TZ1RDJZE7eRxFxaiR
connector_automation/review_settings/allow_non_subscribers - 1
connector_configuration/abandoned_carts/allow_non_subscribers - 1
sync_settings/addressbook/allow_non_subscribers - 1
connector_developer_settings/system_alerts/user_roles - 1
```

Elastic search ping command output:

```
$ curl -XGET localhost:9200
{
  "name" : "user-pc",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "RfVO4Tj6TcCQWwyDegap3g",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.12.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    "build_hash" : "3186837139b9c6b6d23c3200870651f10d3343b7",
    "build_date" : "2021-04-20T20:56:39.040728659Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.8.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

.htaccess file contents:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule .* /pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Apache error log has nothing generated whenever I access the site.

Below are the contents added to the Apache access logs when I access the site:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [09/May/2021:19:52:43 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1036 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [09/May/2021:19:52:43 +0300] "GET /icons/blank.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 179 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [09/May/2021:19:52:43 +0300] "GET /icons/unknown.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 179 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [09/May/2021:19:52:43 +0300] "GET /icons/text.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 180 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [09/May/2021:19:52:43 +0300] "GET /icons/folder.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 179 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0"
```

Apache modules loaded:

```
$ apache2ctl -M
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php7_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

I made sure multiple times to convert the permissions of all the files in the directory to www-data user, recursively.
Any help appreciated.

**EDIT**: So I changed my DocumentRoot to /var/www/magento2.4/pub. Now I get a page with no css apparently:
[image]

And every link I try is a 404:
[image]

The rest of the configuration is the same. pub folder has its own default .htaccess file.

Comment: is elastic search enabled ?

Comment: @VibhoreJain Yes, it is running, I will post the test curl command proving it.

Comment: are you getting some error message or error from error logs.

Comment: I checked Apache's logs and they seemed fine, but I will post them. What other logs should I look into apart from that?

Comment: So the problem I had not detected is, as is evident in the conf file, that I have set `DocumentRoot /var/www/magento2.4/pub` but for the rules I have `<Directory /var/www/html/magento2.4/pub>`, a whole `html` off. The joys of copy pasting code and only changing half of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your document root in your Apache virtual host needs to point to /pub directory. It’s mandatory now from v 2.4.2. See here for details. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html

Try updating your virtual host to following and restarting Apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin admin@localhost
 DocumentRoot /var/www/magento2.4/pub/

 <Directory /var/www/magento2.4/pub/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
 </Directory>

 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: .htaccess must change accordignly I suppose? Because the default one tries to rewrite request inside the pub folder.

Comment: No because the pub directory has its own index.php and htaccess file. Web user will never hit the main directory if the document root is set to pub.

Comment: In your original virtual host file you have the main directory AllowOverride set to none. That’s why the main dir htaccess file redirect is being ignored and you’re just seeing the directory contents.

Comment: I had changed that part but had not updated in the question, did now.

Comment: You had not observed it, but I had an extra `http` in the directory of the Directory rules that should not be there, due to copy pasting. Your conf made it work.

Answer (score 1):

Dowloand the .htaccess file to add to your project.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/.htaccess
The .htaccess is required when you run Magento 2 project with apache.

Comment: The .htaccess mentioned in the link you gave in your answer is identical to the one already existing in the project. Do you think there might be a problem in that an index.php is referred even though it does not exist in the directory?

Comment: If it is exited in the project. Please check the rewrite module of apache 
https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-enable-apache-mod_rewrite-on-an-ubuntu-18-04-vps-or-dedicated-server/
Install, enable it and then try to restart apache server.

Comment: ```$ sudo a2enmod rewrite 
[sudo] password for user:                      
Module rewrite already enabled
```

Comment: If enable rewrite mode and restart apache2 doesn't help (Remember to restart the server) . You can try to change the folder config in apache to the pub folder of the project. The problem on seeing the directory file is on the .htaccess file and the rewrite module in my experience. You can try to use the Nginx for your local setup. SInce magento have a sample config file for Nginx.

Comment: Ok I can look into nginx if I see no solution with Apache. Thank you!